# Spring security sessionscope appears to be null when using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, thymeleaf

When login fails with spring security, it throws exception and it displays it in my JSP like this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="errorblock">
        Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
        ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Now I am changing from JSP to Thymeleaf and trying to do the same thing, but when log in fails, the `sessionScope` variable seems to be null.

```
<div th:if="${error}" class="errorblock" th:text="'testing ' + ${sessionScope}">

</div>
```

This prints out `testing null` . When I change view resolver back to JSP, it works nicely. I think I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Thymeleaf, you don't access session variables using the `sessionScope` token name. You use `session` instead. So you need to do something like:

```
<div class="error" 
     th:if="${param.login_error}"
     th:with="errorMsg=${session["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}">
  Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br />
  Reason: <span th:text="${errorMsg}">Wrong input!</span> 
</div>
```

Disclaimer, according to StackOverflow rules: I am the author of Thymeleaf.

Comment: Is there a documentation for that? Or how would I kow to use `session` or `sessionScope` ? Also, where does the `param.login_error` come from? It works, but looks like a dark magic.

Comment: The `param.login_error` is a request parameter created by Spring Security after a login error. You will have to go the Spring Security documentation for that. As for the `session` scope, it's first introduced in page 15 (subsection "Contexts") of the main Thymeleaf Tutorial ("Using Thymeleaf", http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html ) and then used throughout the rest of this and other tutorials and example apps.

Comment: copy pasted your answer, got org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 104; columnNumber: 80; Element type "div" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".  Problem is with the th:with section.

Comment: how do you do this in javascript?

Comment: hello, could I access currently logged in user (and maybe its attributes) via that `session` object to use in an if statement? right now if I use `<div th:text="${session.user}"></div>` for testing, it renders nothing nor throws errors. thanx

Answer (score 5):

The second isn't the same as the first. I'm not sure what you're supposed to get if you invoke the implicit EL variable `sessionScope` without a variable name. How about:

```
${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
```

Besides, are you sure your page joined the session? In JSP there's the `session` directive that controls whether the session scope is available through EL or not.

```
<%@ page session="false|true" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works with Thymeleaf 3.0 & Bootstrap 4.1

```
<div th:if="${param.error} and ${session}" th:with="errorMsg=${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION']}">
     <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger error">
          Reason: <span th:text="${errorMsg}">Demo Invalid input</span>
     </div>
</div>
```